# model hook called, but setupController hook not called in an Ember.Route

Tags: ember.js

From what I understand, `setupController` should always be called when entering an `Ember.Route`.

Setting breakpoints, I observe that the `model` hook gets called, but the `setupController` hook does not.

What could be possible reasons for this?

---

```
var FooBarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        //breakpoint here
        return {
            slug: params.slug,
        };
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        // breakpoint here
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        controller.set('slug', model.slug);
    },
});

export default FooBarRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had this in my `FooBarController`:

```
setup: function() {
    this.updateParentData();
}.on('init'),

updateParentData: function() {
    this.set('controllers.foo.barproperty', this.get('something'));
},
```

wrapping the `.set()` in `Ember.run.next()` fixed the problem for me.

```
setup: function() {
    this.updateParentData();
}.on('init'),

updateParentData: function() {
    Ember.run.next(() => {
        this.set('controllers.foo.barproperty', this.get('something'));
    });
},
```

While I have fixed the problem at hand,
I am unsure what the cause of it was,
and whether this was a bug in my code, or in Ember...
Any explanations?